# openshift java cannot display data in output console

Tags: java, openshift

Does somebody know how to print to console in Eclipse openshift java project ?
I have a class and System.out() some data but I doesn't show in the console. Any idea ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can print as simply with

```
System.out.println("something");
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. Still have nothing in my console output

Comment: Ok, there can be only 3 reasons for this:
1. Code line is not executed ( make brakepoint on it and check if your debuger will stop on it )
2. You have overridden out destination ( can be done but is highly not recommended )
3. You have problem with your eclipse.  ( create normal project and try to print something on console )

Comment: Hi, 1 - How to debug with an Openshift java application ? 2 - If it's overriden out, where ? 3 - My Eclipse works fine I think, because I can print out with a simple java project.